# CMake Correctly pass configuration options to subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I want to pass configuration options (some STRINGs and BOOLs) to a subdirectory with its own CMake project. What is the correct way to do this since all three methods I have found, have major flaws?

1. set(CACHE): You need to use set(CACHE) in the parent project as well, since it cache variables and normal variables don't interact in any logical manner (and it changes depending on the policy). Also you have to set the variable description in the the parent project, which also makes no sense.
2. set(): Not an option since you cannot set any defaults except with a lot of if-statements.
3. option(): Useless since you can only use BOOLs with it.

Is there something that I am missing? How do big projects handle this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "since all three methods I have found, have major flaws?" - I know no problem, where its solutions has no flaws. Each solution has its own restrictions. As for "you have to set the variable description in the the parent project, which also makes no sense." - I don't find it as a "major flaw" at all. That description could be informative like "Select variant of <subproject> which is needed by <superproject>".

Answer (score 2):

Cache variables and normal variables interact logically as of CMake 3.21 with [CMP0126](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0126.html) enabled.

In your project, just write:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(example)

...

# include the next line if subdir is 3rd party
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0126 ON)

set(subdir_SOME_OPTION "value")
add_subdirectory(subdir)
```

The variable [CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0126](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMPNNNN.html) will enable sane cache interactions with normal variables, even when the subproject's `cmake_minimum_required` version is set below 3.21. In short, with CMP0126 normal variables always "win" over cache variables.

If you want `subdir_SOME_OPTION` to remain user-overridable, then you will need to make it into a cache variable with the same type and docstring as the subproject. A bit annoying, yes, but not *too* much of a burden. Alternatively, you can re-export the option with your *own* cache variable like `example_SOME_OPTION` and then `set(subdir_SOME_OPTION "${example_SOME_OPTION}")` if you have some use for this level of indirection.

That would look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(example)

set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0126 ON)

set(example_SOME_OPTION "default-value"
    CACHE STRING "documentation")

set(subdir_SOME_OPTION "${example_SOME_OPTION}")
add_subdirectory(subdir)
```

Comment: You are probably right with the separation of configuring the submodule and caching the user input. But I still find it baffling that CMake still has no fleshed out parameter passing mechanism as part of the core language. And not to mention CMP0126... Changing/Having to change stuff like this is just insane.

Comment: @SkryptX - I can't disagree with you on any of that. One day more projects will be on CMake 3.21+ and we won't have to think about CMP0126 anymore. (btw - I was the one who [complained enough](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22038) to actually get CMP0126 added and implemented).

Comment: With those policies sometimes I thing the cmake developers are a bit too afraid of hyrum's law...

Comment: @fabian The backwards compatibility that it enables is honestly amazing. But it cannot be your get-out-of-jail-free-card to making stupid design decisions in the first place. If CMake would have a clearer development vision and publish clear guidelines how to use CMake correctly, stuff like this would not happen and the language would be based on sensible principles, that are already invented by so many different programming languages. That lays a solid foundation and you will never have to change those in decades.

Comment: @SkryptX - unfortunately the ship has completely sailed on that. I don't think CMake can be completely fixed through policies. CMake's declarative core (targets with properties that can contain generator expressions) is actually pretty decent, but the configuration language was designed (as far as I can tell) without regard to _any_ prior art, is terrible, and has remained essentially unchanged since it was introduced. Fixing the scoping rules, function calling convention, core data structures, etc. would be tantamount to a rewrite.

Comment: @SkryptX I'm pretty sure the old behaviour for the policy was never intended and was a bug in the first place.

Comment: @AlexReinking Nice to meet someone that sees it the same way as I do :) Maybe we get CMake 4 with all these things... It took Python only 10 short years to transition from 2 to 3 :D

Comment: "sane interaction", you got to be kidding me? Setting a CACHE variable can silently fail because of that change. There is nothing sane about any of that.

Comment: @Vinci - when can setting a cache variable fail?

Comment: I'm sorry it has been late yesterday. I've had PATH and INTERNAL attributes mixed up in my code. Please ignore my rant. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct way

`add_subdirectory` inherits all variables. Just `set()` the variable.

> Is there something that I am missing?

`option()` and `set(.... CACHE)` are for configuration options and/or cache variables. A variable doesn't have to be in cache to be visible in a subdirectory. Just `set()` it normally. Set a variable to be in cache, if you have a specific reason for it, like you want the variable to be preserved between configuration runs, or it should show up in ccmake and gui apps. That's what CACHE variables are for.

> How do big projects handle this kind of problem?

They `set()` the variables. For example [kwsys in cmake sources](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L355).

Comment: How do you handle default values? Is there a more efficient way than `if`?

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/kwsys/CMakeLists.txt#L212 `Is there a more efficient way than if?` Your overall post is odd for me. You have a solution, right in front of you, but you seem not to take it because "it's a lot of `if` statements". I can only recommend to just write those if statements. CMake as a language is verbose. `if` is very _efficient_, I think it is the most efficient way to check something in CMake.

Comment: I'm currently learning CMake and may have gotten a bit frustrated with CMake the last two weeks. I really struggle to find good examples of "modern CMake" and how to correctly structure a project and so many features are hidden or not well thought out like this example. Like the CMake Devs were _this_ close to providing a useful parameter passing mechanism, but no... Implicit variables and a pile of `if` statements it is... `option` and `set(CACHE)` with tiny fixes could be one-line-solutions to this extremely common problem.

Answer (score 1):

All three methods are usable depending on the way how subproject processes its parameter and how the outer project's setting is intended to interact with the user.

1. Inner project works with the CACHE variable: creates it using `set(CACHE)` or `option()`:

   ```
   # Inner project
   set(FOO_TOOL_PATH "/inner/path" PATH "Path to foo tool")
   option(ENABLE_BAR "Whether need to use bar" FALSE)
   ```

   In that case the outer project could set CACHE variable too:

   ```
   # Outer project, user cannot modify the value.
   set(FOO_TOOL_PATH "/outer/path" INTERNAL "Path to foo tool, selected by <me>")
   # Use `set` because we need to use INTERNAL keyword and 'option()' doesn't support it.
   set(ENABLE_BAR TRUE INTERNAL "Need to use bar")
   ```

   or, if it wants the value to be modifiable by the user,

   ```
   # Outer project, user may modify that value.
   set(FOO_TOOL_PATH "/outer/path" PATH "Path to foo tool")
   option(ENABLE_BAR "Whether need to use bar" TRUE)
   ```
2. Inner projects works with normal (non-CACHE) variable: checks its existence using `if` and, if unset, possibly creates using `set()`:

   ```
   # Inner project
   if(NOT FOO_TOOL_PATH)
      set(FOO_TOOL_PATH "/inner/path")
   endif()
   ```

   If the outer project wants to assign fixed value to the variable, then the variable could be defined using plain `set()`:

   ```
   # Outer project, user cannot modify the value.
   set(FOO_TOOL_PATH "/outer/path")
   ```

   If the outer project wants the value to be modifiable by the user, then it could use either `if` plus `set()`, like the inner project

   ```
   # Outer project, user may modify that value.
   if(NOT FOO_TOOL_PATH)
      set(FOO_TOOL_PATH "/outer/path")
   endif()
   ```

   or it could create a CACHE variable:

   ```
   # Outer project, user may modify that value.
   set(FOO_TOOL_PATH "/outer/path" CACHE PATH "Path to foo tool")
   ```